# Why is there no conversion of nil to symbol in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Given that `nil.to_s` is an empty string `''` and `:"".to_s` is an empty string as well, I can't help but wonder why `nil.to_sym` gives an error. It seems logical to me that `nil.to_sym` would give an empty symbol `:""`. Am I missing something or could this be a useful drop-in extension of `NilClass`?

Comment: Undoubtedly, Matz would ask: What is the use case?

Comment: sawa f.e. case-switching over something.to_sym where something could be nil. I don't really care if it's nil here.

Comment: go with `nil.to_s.to_sym`

Answer (score 3):

Until recent, symbols, unlike strings, could not be garbage collected, so people had to be more careful about generating symbols from some random object. Symbol is to be used when its inventory is predetermined; it is not supposed to be used to express an open range of objects.

Recently, garbage collection for symbols was introduced, but you still don't need `nil.to_sym`; if your purpose is just to safely apply a symbol class's instance method, then you don't need to convert it to a symbol first as you can just use the safety navigation operator on it.

```
foo&.some_symbol_method
```

Comment: I see, the `&.` operator is basically a syntax sugar for Rails `try` method?

Comment: It's not identical. It only operates on `nil`, not `false`.  `false.try(:upcase)` will  return nil, but `false&.upcase` will raise undefined method.  Also `try` (unlike `try!`) will return nil if the object is not nil but has no such method... `"hello".try(:odd?)` returns nil, `"Hello"&.odd?` raises undefined method

Comment: So `&.` isn't chainable, unlike `try`? Thanks, that was helpful

Comment: "it is not supposed to be used to express an open range of objects" - but we're talking about precisely ONE object here - the only instance of NilClass, so I can't see how this can hurt garbage collection/memory consumption.

Comment: @Dr.Strangelove Aren't you trying to apply it to something you don't know whether it is `nil` or not, (i.e., open ended)? In that case, the problem is not particularly with `nil`, but with applying to an open thing. That is what I am mentioning.

Comment: The problem is a `to_sym` interface uniformity: `nil` is almost the only one object without `to_sym` method. Given it's widespread use I feel it's logical to fix this issue by implementing this interface on `NilClass`.

Comment: What? There are exactly *two* implementations of `to_sym` in the Ruby core library: `Symbol#to_sym` (the identity method) and `String#to_sym`. It's exactly the other way around: with your suggestion, `nil` would be almost the only one object *with* a `to_sym` method.